# From which direction should a modal progress bar enter the scene?

Tags: modal-dialog, progress-bar

I have a form to create a new Widget. After the user presses "Create," a modal progress bar appears and shows the user the status of the background process that saves the Widget. How should the modal appear?

- From the right (on LTR languages), representing the "next stage" of the Widget creation process
- From the top or within, representing a sub-process of the "current stage" of the Widget creation process
- Other

I don't know whether this has any bearing, but in some cases there will be another form in the Widget creation process after the background build has finished.

Comment: Not sure what you mean "from which direction", most modal progress bars just appear; is this one animated to pop in? If so I'd just animate it like most of your pop ups animate in. I assume this isn't the only animated element?

Comment: "Pop in" is certainly a valid direction. Other modals do use popIn, but there are no other modals that are conceptually the next stage of a process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Apple HIG would make it appear from the top... on the other side, Apple HIG is about editing a document (it's a document-based UI)

On the other side, on flow diagrams, I add such processes as a separate keyscreen (albeit with a special **P1**, **P2**, etc numbering, meaning *processing*, as opposed to **KS1**, meaning *key screen*), so in terms of sequential navigation, it would be logical to make it come from the right.

It depends wether:

- the other steps are user navigatable (eg. explicit *Next* / *Back* buttons) - then it's not a step, it isn't navigatable
- it's needed to calculate the next step - then it belongs to the next step, which could come in with a loading screen/progress bar first perhaps
- there's only one step of it (eg, it's about saving a document) - then it's not a wizard, but a document, Apple HIG rules kick in, from top.
- is it a bit out of the context (eg. it's done for each step, or it's a parallel activity, like when an OS installer formats disks, install apps acting on user request) - then it's from the top, denoting it comes from a parallel universe
- user data can be collected beforehand - today's installers work this way: they collect all the data they need, then step one last time, and show the progress bar of acting on the full process

Does this help you?

Comment: I was hoping for an answer like this -- one that asks further questions and gives reasons rather than just picks a direction. Thanks :)

Comment: Isn't what UX is about? I don't like when UX designers come with a pdf, full of screen mockups or nearly-full visuals, but no explanation on why things are that way.. This is how Xerox Star was born: problem, explanation. This is how design patterns are... This is what design is: create with an intent